# Views and memory management in ios5

Tags: memory, ios5, view, automatic-ref-counting

I am just wondering if there is any memory leaks in the approach i am currently having:

I am adding multiple subviews to a view and have define each of those subviews as property with the retain keyword. When the function viewDidUnload is called do i need to set the pointer to those subviews to nil or this is done automatically since i am using ARC. I don't do anything right now within the viewDidUnload function.

Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By doing nothing in `viewDidUnload`, you are keeping those subviews around, but you aren't leaking them.

A leaked object is still in memory but you have no way to reach it (because there are no pointers left pointing at it).  These subviews aren't leaked, because you still have your view controller object with pointers to the subviews.  When the view controller is deallocated, it will release the subviews, and then they will be deallocated, not leaked.  (If the view controller itself becomes leaked, *then* the subviews are also leaked.)

However, you should release the subviews in `viewDidUnload`, by setting the properties or instance variables to `nil`.  Why?  The system unloads your view, and sends you `viewDidUnload`, when it is low on memory.  If you do nothing in `viewDidUnload`, then you're keeping those subview objects around, taking up memory, when you don't need them to.

Comment: Hi Rob - in case i have declared a weak pointer to an IBOutlet view I don't need to set its pointer to nil right? this will be done automatically after the viewDidUnload function? I have seen some implementation where the reference to subviews is weak so now i am confuse if i should use strong properties to reference subviews. Since i am creating those subviews i thought at first that i am the owner of those subviews and so those reference should be declare with a strong keyword. Thanks!

Comment: I have separate my second question in a new post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9343092/should-all-reference-to-programmactically-created-subviews-declared-as-weak