# Should all reference to programmactically created subviews declared as weak?

Tags: ios, memory-management, automatic-ref-counting

I am getting confuse weither reference to subviews i am creating in a view should be declared with the weak or strong keyword when using ARC in iOS5.

Here is a sample of my header file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@class SCLGridView;

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
    @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *hiddenBrowserView; 
    @property (strong, nonatomic) SCLGridView *gridView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *backgroundView; 
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIView *backgroundShadowView;
    @property (strong, nonatomic) UIPopoverController* popOverController;
@end
```

I run under the impression that the views i am creating and want to reference should be declare with the strong keyword because i am owning those views(i create them). However i have declared the hiddenBrowserView as weak because i am referencing a view i have created in the storyboard. Is this apporach correct or i should make all those view reference as weak even for the reference to views i create programmatically? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know the subviews are strongly referenced by the main view of your controller. So there is no purpose of referencing them strong because the'll be useless when your main view goes down.

1. In other way, you *create* a subviews programmatically, and *add* them to your controller's main view.
2. Your controller's main view references them **strongly**.
3. And you point at this views with **weak** properties.
4. When your controller's main view is *deallocated*, so are the subviews.

Comment: Thanks for your answer: i think you are correct. I believe my confusion comes from the fact that if you have a pointer on a view you are just created you not necessarily have to reference it strongly through this pointer since as you said the controller main view will take care to reference them strongly.